# Getting The Data Right For A Model

Tags: data, logistic-regression

I'm looking to use a logistic regression model to predict who is most likely to suffer a heart attack within a population.

I have a dependent variable flag for has heart attack along with some other data such as age, obesity flag, smoking status etc.

The issue is that the population data is a latest snapshot of the current population and not as at the time the event happend. My concern is that somebody might have turned their life around since the event and while at the time they suffered a heart attack they smoked and had an unhealthy BMI they are now a non-smoker with a healthy BMI which could potentially lead to an inaccurate model.

Would a solution to this be to replace the values where the dependent variable is true with the data that would have been correct at the time the event took place?